# PHP if execution

Tags: php, if-statement, operator-precedence

In PHP if you have the following code does $b get evaluated since $a will cause the if statement to return false?

```
$a = false;
$b = true;

if ($a && $b) {
  // more code here
}
```

also if $b does get evaluated are there ever circumstances where a portion of an if statement may not be evaluated as the processor already knows that the value to be false?

Comment: Iirc, no, the evaluation will stop (and fail) at $a.

Comment: php evaluates quite lazy. since $a is false, the expression will be false regardless of $b, so there is no reason to evaluate $b. (extensively covered in the manual and tutorials, AFAICR). also, you could've checked yourself by using functions that echo something and return a boolean.

Comment: No it will not be evaluated because it short circuits.

Comment: Also with opcache there are cases when the entire if isn't executed.

Comment: In theory, you shouldn't assume an order of operations since future versions may change it and evaluate `$b` and then `$a`. In practice everyone already assumes that `$b` is not evaluated so it's doubtful that this change will ever happen, so as it stands now, `$a` is evaluated and if it's false then the whole `if` fails (without evaluating `$b`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluation of `&&` is stopped as soon as it hits the `false` condition.

These (`&&`) are short-circuit operators, so they don't go to check second condition if the first one true (in case of OR) or false(in case of AND).

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

---

From documentation:

```
<?php

// --------------------
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit

$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

Answer (score 1):

***Evaluation of logical expressions is stopped as soon as the result is known***.

If `$a` is false, `$b` will not get evaluated, as it won't change the (`$a && $b`) result.

A consequence of that is that if the evaluation of `$b` requires more ressources than the evaluation of `$a`, starts your test condition with `$a`.

**But be aware that**:

> PHP does not (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is evaluated and code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should be avoided, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or depending on the surrounding code. ([Source php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php))

So you should not assume `$b` is never evaluated if `$a` is false, as it may change in the future (says php docs).

Comment: Thanks for the clariffication useful to know